# Comparing the third bit of a number

Tags: java, editing

The program below checks if the third bit of a number is 1. I took a number with 1 only on the third bit (4) and I am comparing it with a number entered from a user.

So far the program works, but I am looking for different approach. I want to know if there is another way to get the same result.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Eneter number: ");
int number = sc.nextInt();
int snum = 4;
int check = number & snum;
if (check == snum)
{
    System.out.println("The third bit 1.");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("The third bit is not 1.");
}
sc.close();
```

Comment: You could change your condition to `if ((number & 0x04) > 0)`. This would do practically the same. In this case you wouldn't need the `check` variable.

Comment: Why? Why do you need another way! What's wrong with this way?

Comment: Seems to work, this way I can reduce the amount of code, thank you very much. I am just looking for a different point of view, maybe I can learn new stuff :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shift the number two bits to the right, by dividing it by 4, and than test the last bit (which was the 3rd before shifting) - if the number is odd, it was `1`, else - it was `0`:

```
num = num / 4;
if (num % 2 == 1) //it was 1
else //it was 0
```

But your approach is also a good one.

Comment: Never tought of that, this seems to seemplify the program, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if((number >> 2) & 1)==1) {
       // same code as before.
   }
```

What happens is that your number gets shifted two times to the left so let say your number is 12 --> 1100. So after it's shifted it becomes 0011. Now you can compare the last bit with 1.

Answer (score 0):

There is an infinite number of approach since you can insert many redundant operations. But if you limit it to one arithmetic / logic operation plus one equality test / comparison, the following are some possibilities (test is true for third bit == 1, false for third bit == 0) -

```
(number & 4) != 0  
(number | 4) == number  
(number % 8) >= 4
```